# stack imbalance with variogram()

Tags: r

I've found a problem whit the calculation of the variogram with a dataset.
Till now I've worked with the general dataset and with a subset I extracted without problems. As I extracted another "lombardia" subset, the same code gave me warnings.

```
#Importing the file
dati<-read.csv("/home/.../file.csv", header = TRUE, skip=4, dec = ",")

#Converting to UTM
dati_utm<-spatial_convert(dati)

#I try to extract a subset to "select" a smaller zone to operate on: for Lombardia use 8.5°<long<11.3°, lat>44.5
north_east<-subset(dati, dati$lat>46 & dati$long>11)
north_east_utm<-spatial_convert(north_east)

#That's the dataset that gives me the warnings
lombardia<-subset(dati, dati$lat>44.5 & dati$long<11.3 & dati$long>8.5)
lombardia_utm<-spatial_convert(lombardia)

#Here I extract a subset from the grid
ne.grid<-subset(DEM, DEM$long>11 & DEM$lat>46)
lombardia.grid<-subset(DEM, DEM$lat>44.5 & DEM$long<11.3 & DEM$long>8.5)
lombardia.grid<-spatial_convert(lombardia.grid)
ne.grid<-spatial_convert(ne.grid)


#Here I compute the variogram
zone<-lombardia_utm
my_grid<-lombardia.grid
rm(lombardia_utm)
rm(lombardia.grid)
v.zone.c <- variogram(zone$tm_01 ~ 1, data=zone, cutoff=100, cloud=T)
v.zone <-variogram(zone$tm_01 ~ 1, data=zone)
plot(v.zone)
```

As I run the command for computing "v.zone.c", I receive the following warnings:

```
> v.zone.c <- variogram(zone$tm_01 ~ 1, data=zone, cutoff=100, cloud=T)
Warning: stack imbalance in '.Call', 111 then 112
Warning: stack imbalance in '=', 109 then 110
Warning: stack imbalance in '{', 106 then 107
Warning: stack imbalance in 'for', 99 then 100
Warning: stack imbalance in '{', 96 then 97
Warning: stack imbalance in 'for', 89 then 90
Warning: stack imbalance in '{', 86 then 87
Warning: stack imbalance in 'for', 79 then 80
Warning: stack imbalance in '{', 76 then 77
Warning: stack imbalance in 'for', 69 then 70
Warning: stack imbalance in '{', 66 then 67
```

The function for projecting the data is correct (and is the same for the both datasets), I don't know what these warnings are. I've read that sometimes could be a bug of R, I tried updating the libraries but, after rebooting, it's the same. It's a problem of my code or can I ignore the messages?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: your example is not reproducible and incomplete; it does not make clear from which package `variogram` comes (although I can guess) but neither does it tell where `spatial_convert` comes from. If you can still reproduce this, I would be willing to look at a reproducible example.

Comment: Sorry, variogram() is from gstat package and spatial_convert() is a simple function that I wrote that project data in utm coordinates. I don't know why but now seems that the code works... I'm sorry that I'm not be able to reproduce the warning anymore! Thank you very much Edzer for your response!